# "for notary"? "green hub"? Please help me dictate this video

Tags: listening

I was trying to dictate this video, but there are some words I am not quite sure about, thanks for your help in advance.
The video link is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kIoQs4QpecU
There are 3 places I need help, I put the word in question in double quote, for the 2nd one, I can't make out the word at all, so I just write down what I heard.

- 1）0'24'' -  When I first came here I didn't know what to expect, I
  thought it would be either for "notary" (0:24) or just a normal
  summer camp.
- 2）0'32'' - "miyou"(0:32) is more than just a summer camp
- 3）1'15'' -    What I love about nyma was probably the survival course
  when we learn    how to make a bow drill and the “green”(1:15) hub

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for transcription. which is unlikely to be of use to future visitors.

Comment: Bonus facts―The video is about  New York Military Academy one of the oldest private, military boarding schools in the U.S. Current President of the United States, Donald Trump, composer Stephen Sondheim, and UFC founder Art Davie are among its graduates.  Context informs the transcription.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

either **full military** or just a normal summer camp

**To me it was much more** than just a summer camp (agreed, this is not clear)

bow drill and **debris hut** (I had not heard this term before, but a Google search shows what it is)

Answer (score 0):

1. "When I first came here I didn't know what to expect, I thought it would be either **full military** (0:24) or just a normal summer camp."

The context is helpful here.  The video highlights a youth summer camp at New York Military Academy.  As such it is a youth summer camp with some paramilitary trappings.

2. **NYMA** (0:32) is more than just a summer camp.

The speaker is pronouncing the acronym, which is the subject of the video.

3. What I love about nyma was probably the survival course when we learn how to make a bow drill and the **debris hut** (1:15).

A [debris hut](https://www.wildernesscollege.com/debris-hut.html) is a kind of simple survival shelter. One is briefly pictured during the student's comment.